# Track Changes in Source table and load to History Table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have created a view which has columns that i need to track for any change and load it into a history table. I created a Trigger as below and when i execute change, it only updates the History but does not add a new updated record. Any idea what im doing wrong?

```
 create or replace function asset_h_fn() returns trigger 
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 as $$
begin
  if (asset = 'Insert') then
   insert into asset_history (sys_period,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6) 
   values (tstzrange(lower(OLD.sys_period), current_timestamp), OLD.col1, OLD.col2, OLD.col3, OLD.col4, OLD.col5);
    NEW.sys_period = tstzrange(current_timestamp,null);
    return new;
    return old;
  end if;
end $$ ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `RETURN OLD;` in your code is fortunately unreachable; remove it.

You don't show us the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement, but it must be an `INSTEAD OF` trigger.

A view does not hold any data, it is an SQL statement with a name. So if you want a new row to appear in the view, you have to add a second `INSERT` to the trigger function that inserts a row into the table(s) on which the view is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Well, It depends on how do you define your trigger...
Looking at your code I suppose you should use `CREATE TRIGGER <trigger_name> BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON <table_name> FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE asset_h_fn();`

The key here is `BEFORE INSERT` - if you wish to alter somehow inserted into original table data... If you don't wish to alter it, you should probably use `AFTER INSERT`.

You may read more about defining triggers and see some examples in [official docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-EXAMPLE)